# What is the meaning of (out of) in the first clause of this sentence

Tags: reading-comprehension

We decided to get a Coke 'out of' the machine,but it was out of order.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different uses of "out of" in the same sentence.

The first instance means "*indicating the source or derivation of something*". When you get something from a vending machine it *comes out of* the machine.